# htop memory and ghc rts memory limit correlation

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am trying to test space leak.
I want to limit memory to get OOM faster.
I see in htop my process starts with RES=260m.
I set `+RTS -M265m` but process takes more than that (274m in htop) and nothing happens. Where is OOM?

Comment: Are you compiling with `-rtsopts`? http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#setting-rts-options-on-the-command-line Also, perhaps it's normal that the total size in memory is somewhat bigger than the size of the heap.

Comment: could you show us your test if it can fit in a post?